# C++ class destructor not being called automatically causes memory leak?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++14

(Before anyone asks: **no**, i didn't forget the delete[] statement)

I was fiddling around with dinamically allocated memory and i run into this issue. I think the best way to explain it is to show you these two pieces of code I wrote. They are very similar, but in one of them my class destructor doesn't get called.

```cpp
// memleak.cpp
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Leak {
    vector<int*> list;

  public:
    void init() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            list.push_back(new int[2] {i, i});
        }
    }

    Leak() = default;
    ~Leak() {
        for (auto &i : list) {
            delete[] i;     
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    Leak leak;
    while (true) {
        // I tried explicitly calling the destructor as well,
        // but this somehow causes the same memory to be deleted twice
        // and segfaults
        // leak.~Leak();
        leak = Leak();
        leak.init();
    }
}
```

```cpp
// noleak.cpp
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Leak {
    vector<int*> list;

  public:
    Leak() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            list.push_back(new int[2] {i, i});
        }
    };
    ~Leak() {
        for (auto &i : list) {
            delete[] i;     
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    Leak leak;
    while (true) {
        leak = Leak();
    } 
}
```

I compiled them both with `g++ filename.cpp --std=c++14 && ./a.out` and used `top` to check memory usage.

As you can see, the only difference is that, in `memleak.cpp`, the class constructor doesn't do anything and there is an init() function that does its job. However, if you try this out, you will see that this somehow interferes with the destructor being called and causes a memory leak.

Am i missing something obvious? Thanks in advance.

Also, before anyone suggests not using dinamically allocated memory: I knwow that it isn't always a good practice and so on, but the main thing I'm interested in right now is understanding why my code doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Please read [the rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Comment: how do you know that the destructor is called / not called ?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 i simply added some printf statements in the code

Comment: why remove them when posting here? Your question is actually about some output of your code, but there is no output in the code you posted here

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 i removed them just to make the code easier to read. As I said, you can see there is a problem just by running `top` and looking at the memory usage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is constructing a temporary object and then assigning it. Since you didn't write an assignment operator, you get a default one. The default one just copies the vector `list`.

In the first code you have:

1. Create a temporary `Leak` object. It has no pointers in its vector.
2. Assign the temporary object to the `leak` object. This copies the vector (overwriting the old one)
3. Delete the temporary object, this deletes 0 pointers since its vector is empty.
4. Allocate a bunch of memory and store the pointers in the vector.
5. Repeat.

In the second code you have:

1. Create a temporary `Leak` object. Allocate some memory and store the pointers in its vector.
2. Assign the temporary object to the `leak` object. This copies the vector (overwriting the old one)
3. Delete the temporary object, this deletes the 10 pointers in the temporary object's vector.
4. Repeat.

Note that after `leak = Leak();` the same pointers that were in the temporary object's vector are also in `leak`'s vector. Even if they were deleted.

To fix this, you should write an `operator =` for your class. The [rule of 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) is a way to remember that if you have a destructor, you *usually* need to also write a copy constructor and copy assignment operator. (Since C++11 you can optionally also write a move constructor and move assignment operator, making it the rule of 5)

Your assignment operator would delete the pointers in the vector, clear the vector, allocate new memory to hold the int values from the object being assigned, put those pointers in the vector, and copy the int values. So that the old pointers are cleaned up, and the object being assigned *to* becomes a copy of the object being assigned *from*, without sharing the same pointers.

Comment: This was my first analysis but I think there is a bit more to the bug, as the assignment performs a move, not a copy, which I believe should leave the original vector empty. Also beware that your described implementation of `operator =` is not exception-safe.

Comment: @Quentin move doesn't leave the original vector empty. Original vector *is in a valid but unspecified state afterwards.*

Comment: @Zereges that is mildly surprising to me, but it does explain the observed behaviour.

Comment: @Zereges Actually, it's [guaranteed to be empty](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector).

Comment: @super it seems that the move-constructor and the [move-assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator%3D) have different guarantees... What?

Comment: @Quentin Oh, that's very surprising.

Comment: @Zereges • in general, the standard C++ library leaves objects in a "valid but unspecified" state.  Some objects, like `std::vector` or `std::unique_ptr` have additional guarantees.  For your own classes, when they are moved from they are left in whatever state you programmed them to to be in, which can be valid and specified (thanks to Howard Hinnant for pointing this tidbit out)... or can set a "don't touch me" bool flag and then call `std::terminate` (or `assert`) if any operation other than destruction or reassignment is done.

Comment: @Quentin - This class has a user provided destructor. It supresses implicit move operations.

Answer (score 1):

Your class doesn't respect the [rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). The default-generated <s>move-assignment</s> copy-assignment operator in `leak = Leak();` makes `leak` reference the contents of the temporary `Leak` object, which it deletes promptly at the end of its lifetime, leaving `leak` with dangling pointers which it will later try to delete again.

<s>Note: this could have gone unnoticed if your implementation of `std::vector` systematically emptied the original vector upon moving, but [that is not guaranteed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator%3D).</s>

Note 2: the striked out parts above I wrote without realizing that, as [StoryTeller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66652015/c-class-destructor-not-being-called-automatically-causes-memory-leak/66652214?noredirect=1#comment117831580_66652214) pointed out to me, your class does *not* generate a move-assignment operator [because it has a user-declared destructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment#Implicitly-declared_move_assignment_operator). A copy-assignment operator is generated and used instead.

Use smart pointers and containers to model your classes (`std::vector<std::array<int, 2>>`, `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` or `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int[]>>`). Do not use `new`, `delete` and raw owning pointers. In the exceedingly rare case where you may need them, be sure to encapsulate them tightly and to carefully apply the aforementioned rule of 3/5/0 (including exception handling).